# Create an UL-list with a text input and button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write some text, click a button and the text added has to make a list.

This is what I have at the moment :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>3-2</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/oefening3-2.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
<p> <span> geef een tekst in<input type="text" id="waarde"> <input type="button" value="Voeg toe" onClick="a();"></span></p>
<ol>
<p> <span id="waarden"> waarde </span> </p>
</ol>
```

And the Javascript code :

```
function a()
{
var ingevoerd = document.getElementById("waarde").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("waarden").add(ingevoerd);  
}
```

I can understand it doesnt make much sence but I have not really a clue how to do this. Enter some text, click the button and the text has to be in a not numbered list. Can annyone help me out? Would be much appreciated!

Kind regards!

Comment: Are the input values comma separated? White space separated? Separated by something else entirely?  How would a function know how to separate the items?

Comment: In the html code I have the <ol> code? As I said I have not a good idea how to do this...

Comment: No, I mean when the user inputs values is s/he doing: (value1, value2, value3) or (value1 value2 value3) or (value1 # value2 # value3).  Give me an example of what the user should be inputting.

Comment: Unless you want to add each value on button click to a list?

Comment: yes, the user types in 1 thing and then clicks on the button... the user types in the 2nd thing and click on the button. And each time the text goe's on a different list item. Greetings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML:

```
geef een tekst in<input type="text" id="waarde">
<input type="button" value="Voeg toe" onClick="a()">
<ul id="waarden"></ul>
```

Javascript code:

```
function a() {
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("waarde").value);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("waarden").appendChild(node);
}
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/y1fk1q70/

---

*Explanation:*

The HTML consists of a few elements:

- Text
- Text Input
- Button
- Unordered List

The button click handler is instructed to execute function `a` when clicked.

The Javascript then performs the following steps:

1. Create a list node element. (Not yet attached to DOM [the page].)
2. Grab the text value of our Text Input and create a text node element from it. (Also not yet attached to DOM.)
3. Append Text Node to the List Node.
4. Append the List Node to the unordered list in the DOM.